# Directive parameters are overriden when using ControllerAs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use one directive with different parameter value and the value of first parameter in directive is overriden by second.

This is my html parent

```
<div finals-match-row team="foo"></div>
<div finals-match-row team="bar"></div>
```

and this is directive

```
angular.module('ViewTournament')

.directive('finalsMatchRow', function () {
    return {
        bindToController: {
            team: '@'
        },
        template: "<p>{{ctrl.team}}</p>",
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: function () {
            var ctrl = this;
        }
    }
});
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Lwa.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1093w.png)

When I am using scope everything seems ok

Comment: Try adding `bindToController: true,` to the directive object (You can read more [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your directive to

```
directive('finalsMatchRow', function() {
    return {
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            team: '@'
        },
        template: "<p>{{ctrl.team}}</p>",
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: function() {
            var ctrl = this;
        }
    }
});
```